# pip install package with submodule

Tags: python, pip, git-submodules, python-packaging

I'm trying to install a python package from pip which contains a submodule. When I do `pip install my-package` on machine A (with pip 21.1.3), everything works fine. However, when I install it on machine B (with pip 20.3.4), the installation fails because some files from the submodule could not be found.

I additionally try to `git clone --recurse-submodule https://github.com/link/to/my-package`, and then install from the locally cloned repo. In this way the package could be normally installed. This should confirm that the issue is about `pip install` somehow does not download the submodule?

I checked the release log of [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/), but seems there is no updates about submodule from 20.3.4 to 21.1.3. Although the problem could be solved now, I wonder how this happens? Is it because of `pip` update which I did not notices, or is it even machine-dependent (if so, how?)

Sidenotes:

1. the version of package I installed on machine A, B and cloned repo are same;
2. machine A is Debian 10, and machine B is CentOS 7'

Comment: You may need to verify that the **git** submodules on the two different machines are in fact identical, perhaps some changes to the submodule commit ids may not have been fully synchronized.  Ensure that the project is fully cloned/fetched and all correct commits have been fully checked out.

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks! tho I'm not sure how to check the submodule commit if it's installed via `pip install`? 
But this is indeed helpful as when I checked the `site-packages` folder on machine one, I found there are only 3 files related to it: `my-package.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, `.dist-info`, and `my-package.libs`. I don't know much about pip package installation, but could this mean that Machine A happens to matched the released wheel, so the package doesn't need to build from scratch thus avoid the problem. While machine B doesn't find a matched wheel, so the problem occurs while building?

Comment: Looks like you got a complete mismatch between sources and version installed between the two machine. You have not indicate exactly how or where those submodules relate to your current git repository, you should run `git show` on every git repo relates to your top level `my-package` between the two machine to ensure they have the same checked-out commit, and run `pip freeze` on both machines to see that the installed versions are available.  Without real diagnostic details it is impossible for anyone else but those with access to your machines to make any real recommendations.

Comment: I see. I'll try to reach out to the ppl who hv access to both machine then. Thanks!